# AngularJS passing variable from html to controller on href

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I know basic angular and i am working on a project in which i hve this code

```
<div>
    <a href="#!/views/products?productId=98" target="_blank">
        <img src="images/x-{{product.productId}}.png"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Right now, I have `productId` as a hardcoded value. What i want that this productId is actually `product.productId` and in controller, I can use this `productId` when it is clicked to fetch further details.

Here is my `ProductController`

```
.controller('ProductCtrl',function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/products').

        success(function(data) {
              $scope.product = data;
        });
})
```

I want `http://localhost:8080/api/products` this to pass a `queryParameter` as `http://localhost:8080/api/products?id=XX` where id is `product.productId` from the html i put above.

How can i acehive this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div>
    <a href="#" ng-click="getMoreDetails(product.productId)" target="_blank">
        <img src="images/x-{{product.productId}}.png"/>
    </a>
</div>

.controller('ProductCtrl',function($scope, $http) {
   $scope.getMoreDetails = function(id){
      $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/products' + id).

        success(function(data) {
              $scope.product = data;
        });
})
```

and maybe just use a dialog or lightbox